# Can't install Xdebug on PHP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug

Trying to install Xdebug so I can debug PHP with VS Code, followed the instructions of the page step by step, reference [Xdebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard).

1. Download `php_xdebug-3.1.6-8.1-vs16-x86_64.dll`
2. Move the downloaded file to `\xampp\php\ext`, and rename it to `php_xdebug.dll`
3. Update `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and add the line:
4. `zend_extension = xdebug`
5. Restart the Apache Webserver

To verify correct installation run `cmd` and type `php -v`, output should list Xdebug installed:

```text
PHP 7.4.10 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2020 09:37:14) ( NTS DEBUG )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.4.10-dev, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
  with Xdebug v3.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethan
```

Installation is trivial, I don't have cloned .ini files, I'm getting the right dll from the page, I'm restarting Apache, my renameing of the dll is right. I don't know what is going on, my output from cmd is:

```text
C:\Users\User>php -v
PHP 8.1.13 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2022 15:49:14) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.13, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

My PHP version is: 8.1.12

Also tried changing the ini file to

```ini
;zend_extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

which is the actual path where the dll is located. Also my PHP is TS, so is the file it's downloading from the wizard. Any hints?

Comment: Make sure you remove that first semi-colon before `zend_extension`. That comments out the line so it's not processed

Comment: This was the problem, didn't know the semicolons were comments as I never edited a ini file in my life, just started learning on this development subject, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As @aynber said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74633842/cant-install-xdebug-on-php#comment131737439_74633842), semicolon is used for indicating comments and therefore the line
`zend_extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"`
is not processed